# Handling IOExceptions while actually receiving data in Java

Tags: java, twitter, exception, httprequest

At the moment I am receiving streaming data from twitter correctly using http requests. However, when i test it e.g disconnect the client from the internet(while receiving data), I stop receiving data anymore which is reasonable. However, I want to be able to capture that change of connectivity and throw an exception or restart the process again.

Let's say the code looks like this:

```
public void streamData() throws IOException{
final URL url = new URL(sample);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
....
....
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

while ((character = rd.read()) != -1)
            {
            char ch = (char) character; //writing character by character
            System.out.print(ch);
            //if connection has broken send an error
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you post up the code you're using?

Comment: i dont think is relevant... it's a simple http request with authentication, reading character by character received streaming data...

Comment: I have added the relevant part of the code, where i basically want to check for connectivity

Comment: How exactly are you connecting? To my experience, the `URLConnection` and `Socket` would just throw `IOException` with kind of a "connection reset" message on `read()` of its `InputStream`. Edit: how are you constructing the `rd`? Isn't it some wrapper which suppresses any `IOException` thrown by the delegatee?

Comment: final URL url = new URL(sample);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); I also use httpPost for a different method. The point is that i would get an exception at the initialization of connection but not during the actual streaming of data.The IOException it is possible to be thrown but is not..

Comment: So... the `streamData()` method did in your case not throw an `IOException` when the connection is reset by the other side?

Comment: The connection is deliberately dropped by me, to check what is going to happen in a real life connectivity issue. But, yes, i dont get any exception on no connection while receiving data. It just stop receiving and the application just hangs...